# Android TV AppBar

Tags: android

I have recently jumped into the world of android tv programming.  I find the best way to learn is to understand and extend already existing samples. To this end I have taken the androdTv lean back sample created by android studio and have been successfully making changes.  One issue I am having is trying to figure out is how to add the menu/appbar at the top of the screen that contains to the left voice search and to the right the time and settings icon as seen on a few android tv products.  The sample already contains a search icon but I’m looking to replace that with a standard appbar.  Any help/pointers/suggestions would be welcome.  Been at this for over a week now.

Update: I think I found the answer
https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-customize-the-title-view-in-the-verticalgridfragment-android-tv-72741d915a5c

Comment: Prefer made an answer than add your answer in your question. You can [answer]